# How to combine scrolling of ListView and TableLayout in Android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, tablelayout

I had a ListView and a Table Layout in a horizontal linear layout. I want to combine scrolling of both the views i.e., if I scroll List view, the table layout should also be scrolled and vice versa. I cannot use a scrollview, because it is not recommended to put List view inside a scroll view.

Please suggest,

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would like to put a listview in a scroll view? 
Because a Listview already is scrollable as far as i remember...

It sounds a little bit strange.. You have horizontal rows (horizontal linear layout) within a table which are horizontal and vertical rows (rows/colums) within a listview which is already scrollable? And a listview are horizontal rows again..

---

Edit.. 
Or i don't understand you well, and you have a listview and a table layout in a horizontal layout. but then you can but the table layout within a scrollview.. this way the scrollview doesn't contain the list view.

Please explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the ListView is small enough so that it can be scrolled simultaneously with a TableLayout then maybe you could simply replace the ListView with a LinearLayout and put both the TableLayout and the LinearLayout in a ScrollView.